# .task's won't reload when changing @State variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Lets say that I had a `.task`:

```swift
Text(shlokadd)
  .task {
      shlokadd = await callApi(chapter: "\(chapter)", shloka: "\(shloka)")[0]
  }
```

It basically just changes a Text's result based on a async function that takes @State parameters.

Lets say I change the @State parameters:

```swift
Button("Previous") {
    if Int(chapter) == 1 && Int(shloka) == 1 {} else {
        if Int(shloka) == 1 {
            self.chapter = String(Int(self.chapter)! - 1)
            self.shloka = shlokas[Int(self.chapter)! - 1]
        }
        else {
            self.shloka = String(Int(self.shloka)! - 1)
        }
    }                     
}
```

I read that if you change @State parameters, the view will reload. Other parts of the view that depend on the variables reload well, except for this `.task` part. Is there a way to reload this part too, or am I just being dumb?

I tried googling this, but I didn't come across anything. I'm a beginner in SwiftUI, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something obvious wrong.

Comment: You can provide an `id` to the `task` modifier -- it will rerun whenever the `id` changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `@State` property to the `.task` modifier and it will execute the task when the property changes.

```
.task(id: chapter) {
   shlokadd = await callApi(chapter: "\(chapter)", shloka: "\(shloka)")[0]
}
```

I used `chapter` here since I am not sure which property you want to trigger on.

If you want to trigger a task on multiple properties you can use a computed property to combine those properties into one and use that for the `id:` argument